# Can't run Java with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I've been trying to make an app run with maven with `mvn exec:exec` or `mvn exec:java` but keep on getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.inpun.alt.gaecl.AppEngineShell
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.inpun</groupId>
    <artifactId>gael</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>GAE Command Line</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
        <gae.version>1.8.8</gae.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.inpun.alt.gaecl.AppEngineShell</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What could be the problem with this code that is causing the `ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: Someone has to ask this: is `com.inpun.alt.gaecl.AppEngineShell` a correct class?

Comment: Yes, its correct. See https://github.com/inpun/gaecl/blob/master/src/com/inpun/alt/gaecl/AppEngineShell.java

Comment: The error means that the class `com.inpun.alt.gaecl.AppEngineShell` is not found. It's not in your classpath, probably because there's something incorrectly specified in the dependencies of your project.

Comment: Did you try doing `mvn clean install` just before you do `mvn exec:java`?

Comment: @Jesper I updated the question with the complete POM. Yes it seems something is wrong, but not sure what is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally missed this one, since the project was originally a ant project, the `src` folder structure must be `src/main/java`

Answer (score 1):

Try running `mvn package exec:java`.

Comment: `install` is not necessary, that'd only slow things down and slowly fill the HDD, `package` is more than enough

Comment: It is necessary to compile code before you could run it.

Comment: um ... you obviously dont know how maven works. I recommend reading the documentation before you start using such a powerful tool, everything else will get you into big trouble sometime. `package` does everything up to its own lifecycle, including `compile`. Maybe start with simple commandline-compiling at first, maven is obviously too complex for you right now.

Comment: `package` or `install` is irrelevant for the purposes of this particular question. I admired your cockiness though, gave me a good chuckle.

Comment: that ... doesnt make any sense whatsoever, in fact you're contradicting yourself.